# Android: Unable to get list of directories under directory obtained from DIRECTORY_DCIM

Tags: android, camera

Guys!

This is my first question here and I am a beginner in Android app development, so please excuse me if my question seems futile. I am developing my Android app in which I am trying to get the number of photos taken by the Android phone's default Camera app.For this purpose, I wrote following code. This code works fine on my Android device having OS 4.x while the same code doesn't work on my Android device having OS 6.x and 7.x.

My code:

```
package com.local.cameraphotos;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public void get_no_of_pictures(File directory){

      int picture_count = 0;
      int video_count = 0;

      Log.e("Camera", "Going to get files in directory:" + directory);

      if(directory != null) {

         File[] files = directory.listFiles();
         if(files != null) {
            for (File CurFile : files) {
               if (CurFile.isDirectory()) {

                  if(CurFile.getName().equals("100MEDIA")) {
                     Log.e("Camera", "Directory name:" + CurFile.getName());
                     get_no_of_pictures(CurFile);
                  }else if (CurFile.getName().equals("Camera")) {
                     Log.e("Camera", "Directory name:" + CurFile.getName());
                     get_no_of_pictures(CurFile);
                  }
               }else if (CurFile.isFile()){

                  if(CurFile.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                     picture_count++;
                  else if(CurFile.getName().endsWith(".mp4"))
                     video_count++;
               }

            }
            Log.e("Camera", "Total number of pictures:" + picture_count);
            Log.e("Camera", "Total number of videos:" + video_count);
        }else{
            Log.e("Camera", "Unable to get list of files from CameraDirectory");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   File CameraDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
   get_no_of_pictures(CameraDirectory);

   finish();
}
```

The problem occurs when my code tries to list files using directory.listFiles() then it returns null on Android 7.x and on 6.x but returns valid values on Android 4.x.

My Manifest looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.local.cameraphotos">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="25"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="25"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated as I have already searched for links on this forum about getting the files under a directory on Android file system but I did not come across a case like this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Were you actually granted the permission? Because just because you request it does not mean you are granted the permission especially in versions > L. Look up how to deal with runtime permissions and requesting those permissions.

Comment: Hi Jox!

Thanks for the hint. After I checked for the permission granted or not I found that it was not. Once I added a check for it and asked the user for this permission then it worked.

Comment: Great to hear it helped. I posted this as an answer. Please feel free to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you actually granted the permission? Because just because you request it does not mean you are granted the permission especially in versions > L. Look up how to deal with runtime permissions and requesting those permissions.